# How do I implement Rng and RngCore so I can sample a custom struct type?

Tags: random, rust

I have the following code, where I try to implement `Rng` and `RngCore` for a custom type.

```
#[cfg(test)]
use rand::{Rng, RngCore};

pub const FP751_NUM_WORDS: usize = 12;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Fp751Element(pub (crate) [u64; FP751_NUM_WORDS]);

#[cfg(test)]
impl RngCore for Fp751Element {
    fn next_u64(&mut self) -> u64 {
        self.next_u64()
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
impl Rng for Fp751Element {
    fn gen<Fp751Element>(&mut self) -> Fp751Element {
        let high_limb = self.next_u64() % 246065832128056;

        Fp751Element([
            self.next_u64(),
            self.next_u64(),
            self.next_u64(),
            self.next_u64(),
            self.next_u64(),
            self.next_u64(),
            self.next_u64(),
            self.next_u64(),
            self.next_u64(),
            self.next_u64(),
            self.next_u64(),
            high_limb
        ])
    }
}
```

I want to implement the traits because I later want to use the `quickcheck::Arbitrary` with my type. However, the above type code throws the following error at `impl Rng for Fp751Element` line:

> conflicting implementation in crate `rand`:
> - impl rand::Rng for R
> where R: rand::RngCore, R: ?Sized;

Any ideas?

Comment: Your impl of `RngCore` makes a recursive call. I will assume that this is unrelated.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator Is it possible not to implement `RngCore`? I just need to somehow implement `gen` of `Rng`.

Comment: Why not implement arbitrary directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr** That is the wrong trait to implement if you want to generate random values of your own type.

The trait [`Rng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.4/rand/trait.Rng.html) is an **extension trait** for [`RngCore`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.4/rand/trait.RngCore.html), with a *blanket implementation* included. This means that all types which implement `RngCore` already implement `Rng`, and you should not try to provide it yourself.
Once `Rng` is put into scope, all implementations of `RngCore` will have the extra methods provided there.

However:

> I want to implement the traits because I later want to use the `quickcheck::Arbitrary` with my type.

So this is an XY problem! `RngCore` is designed to create random number generation algorithms, not to define how data types are sampled from a random number source.

```
fn gen<Fp751Element>(&mut self) -> Fp751Element {
```

In fact, the method signature given is very misleading.
In this context, `Fp751Element` is not your struct type `Fp751Element`, but a new generic parameter type with the same name!

In order to implement the generation of your own type with your own distributon, provide a custom [`Distribution`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.4/rand/distributions/trait.Distribution.html) implementation.

```rust
struct Fp751UniformDist;

impl Distribution<Fp751Element> for Fp751UniformDist {
    fn sample<R: Rng + ?Sized>((&self, rng: &mut R) -> Fp751Element {
        let high_limb = rng.next_u64() % 246065832128056;

        Fp751Element([
            rng.next_u64(),
            rng.next_u64(),
            rng.next_u64(),
            rng.next_u64(),
            rng.next_u64(),
            rng.next_u64(),
            rng.next_u64(),
            rng.next_u64(),
            rng.next_u64(),
            rng.next_u64(),
            rng.next_u64(),
            high_limb
        ])
    }
}
```

With this done, one would produce new values of your type using `sample`:

```
let mut rng = thread_rng();
let elem: Fp751Element = rng.sample(Fp751UniformDist);
```

See also:

- [Conflicting implementations of trait in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159226/conflicting-implementations-of-trait-in-rust)
- [How is there a conflicting implementation of `From` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347311/how-is-there-a-conflicting-implementation-of-from-when-using-a-generic-type)
- [How does trait specialization actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600646/how-does-trait-specialization-actually-work)
- [The Rust Rand Book on Custom random types](https://rust-random.github.io/book/guide-values.html#custom-random-types)