# How can I avoid a conflicting implementation when creating a default trait implementation?

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to create a default implementation for a trait in Rust along with one only available for certain types.

Lets say I have this rust code here:

```rs
trait Foo {
    fn function();
}

impl<T> Foo for T {
    fn function() {
        println!("any type")
    }
}

impl<T: From<f32>> Foo for T {
    fn function() {
        println!("only f32 related types")
    }
}
```

This results in a conflicting implementation. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does trait specialization actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600646/how-does-trait-specialization-actually-work)

Answer (score 0):

Since the default implementation for *any type* does not use anything specific to such a type, you can directly define the default implementation in the trait.

Doing so, you can implement this trait for your own types without redefining the same function.

However, it won't be possible for other types (from another crate) because nothing guarantees that such a type will not implement `From<f32>` in a future version of that crate.
If this happened, the two implementations would be conflicting.

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn function(&self) {
        println!("any type")
    }
}

impl<T: From<f32>> Foo for T {
    fn function(&self) {
        println!("only f32 related types")
    }
}

struct MyType(i32);
impl Foo for MyType {}

fn main() {
    let i = 12.34_f32;
    i.function();
    let m = MyType(123);
    m.function();
}
/*
only f32 related types
any type
*/
```

Comment: I want to have this trait implemented for any type automatic tho and only for certain constrained types the implementation should change.